# Arduino sensors with various periods

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

Right now I have DHT11, PIR sensor, relay, and a photocell on the same board. I am planning to upload the data to a web server. But I want both DHT11 and photocell to be uploaded hourly; PIR and relay by every 3s. Is it possible for a single Arduino to perform such thing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Perfectly possible.

How accurate do you need the "hourly"? If you want any form of accuracy at all you will really want to use an RTC module to provide the real time.

Otherwise that, and the higher speed 3s updates, can be timed using the `millis()` function.  The BlinkWithoutDelay example in the IDE shows you the basic idea of working with timestamps to examine elapsed time.

Also there are simple libraries that could help you, such as [SimpleTimer](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer).